# Is the Fuzz onto My Family?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, knowledge

My family is troubled, but it seems it’s been that way for some time.  While some of us claim to be “shrewd businessmen”, this is sadly not the case; you could say we act in some underground operations.  Time and time again, it’s the money that draws us out of our darkness, out of our safety, where a hit is put on almost every one of us.  By now, we should know the danger, but I guess we lack the foresight.  Personally, I’ve never seen a rat among us, but there’s definitely someone who’s turned on the family.

The question is, do you know my family?

Comment: If I made an answer with "no" would it be accepted?

Comment: @MisterEman22 no

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Answer:

> I think I do.

Are you:

> The Whack A Mole arcade game?

some of us claim to be “shrewd businessmen”

> A reference to the American Shrew Mole?

you could say we act in some underground operations

> Moles live in underground burrows.

it’s the money that draws us out of our darkness

> The moles come out when money is put into the arcade game.

where a hit is put on almost every one of us

> They then each proceed to be hit by a mallet

By now, we should know the danger

> Seeing as it happens everytime someone plays a game..

Personally, I’ve never seen a rat among us, but there’s definitely someone who’s turned on the family.

> A reference to the mole-rat?

Comment: Nice! You got it.  I had fun making this quickie, so I'm glad it no one had to beat themselves over the head to work out an answer.

Comment: isn't the final one a reference to the human player who put a coin into the game?

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> Mustelidae? (Mink, shrew, weasel, etc)

“shrewd businessmen”

> Straight-forward pun off shrew

we act in some underground operations

> Live underground

it’s the money that draws us out of our darkness, out of our safety, where a hit is put on almost every one of us

> The pelts can sell for some money

Personally, I’ve never seen a rat among us, but there’s definitely someone who’s turned on the family

> Very similar to rats. Also a wordplay off of "weasel"

Comment: You were definitely picking up on the right things, but alexmc just hit the nail on the head (or mole, as it were...).

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a long shot and I'm really reaching here, but are you:

> Playing cards

Family

> You can categorise them together as a family, especially face cards (the royal family)

Some of us claim to be “shrewd businessmen”

> I have no idea about this one.

You could say we act in some underground operations

> Illegal gambling is called "underground"

It’s the money that draws us out of our darkness

> You put down money to draw cards out of the deck for yourself

Where a hit is put on almost every one of us

> You "hit" in blackjack to get another card

By now, we should know the danger

> Because it's a part of every card game with a deck

I’ve never seen a rat among us

> Ratholing is hiding chips and removing them from play

Fuzz

> 'Fuzz' is reference to shuffling your hand or the desk, sometimes to preserve the initial order

Comment: I like your thought process with this answer, but it definitely was not my intended answer.  It certainly looks like you could have the makings of your own puzzle, though.